# Using the 'wedge product'

Tags: vector-analysis, exterior-algebra

> Given $ω=f\,dx+g\,dy+h\,dz$ such that $ω\wedge dz=0$, what can we conclude about $f, g$ and $h$?

I am going through some textbook exercises and ran across this notation, I am not sure exactly what the $\wedge$ represents. It was always my understanding that $dx\wedge dy$ was just another way of saying $dx\cdot dy$ (the multiplication of the 2 derivatives). Was hoping someone could elaborate on what the $\wedge$ notation exactly means and then maybe I could interpret the question a bit better.

Thanks

Comment: I found [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf) a helpful introduction to the wedge product.

Comment: Keith Conrad's texts are pure gold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ is a real vector space of dimension $n$, $f$ and $g$ be alternating forms of degree $p$ and $q$, then: 
$$f\wedge g(x_1,\ldots,x_{p+q}):=\frac{1}{p!q!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_{p+q}}\varepsilon(\sigma)f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(p)})g(x_{\sigma(p+1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(p+q)}),$$
where $\mathfrak{S}_{p+q}$ is the permutation group of $\{1,\ldots,p+q\}$ and $\varepsilon(\sigma)$ the signature of $\sigma$.

Here are some fundamental properties of the wedge product:

- $(f\wedge g)\wedge h=f\wedge(g\wedge h)$,
- $f\wedge g=(-1)^{\deg(f)\deg(g)}g\wedge f$,
- $(f+\lambda g)\wedge h=f\wedge h+\lambda g\wedge h$,
- If $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are linear forms, then $f_1\wedge\ldots\wedge f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is $\det((f_i(x_j))_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n})$.

I just want to drop a useful result that is a generalization of your question:

> **Proposition.** Let $E$ be a real vector space of dimension $n$, $\omega\in\Lambda^kE^*$ and $\alpha\in E^*\setminus\{0\}$, then:
>   $$\alpha\wedge\omega=0\iff\omega_{\vert\ker(\alpha)}=0\iff\exists\beta\in\Lambda^{k-1}E^*\textrm{ s.t. }\omega=\alpha\wedge\beta.$$

I recommend you think about a proof of this result, think of the incomplete basis theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You can see $\wedge$ as a skew-symmetric product. So for your exercise, $\omega \wedge dz = 0$ translates as $$f\,dx\wedge dz + g \,dy\wedge dz = 0,$$and since the "symbols" $\{dx \wedge dy, dx \wedge dz, dy\wedge dz\}$ are linearly independent, we get $f=g=0$. And $h$ can be anything.

Now that we got that out of the way, let's understand what is going on. If $V$ is a vector space and $T,S$ are $k$-linear and $\ell$-linear, we define $${\rm Alt}(T)(v_1,\ldots, v_k) = \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_k}{\rm sgn}(\sigma) T(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(k)}).$$Then $$T \wedge S \doteq \frac{(k+\ell)!}{k!\ell!}{\rm Alt}(T\otimes S),$$where $T\otimes S$ denotes the tensor product of $T$ and $S$. One can prove that if $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is a basis for $V$, then $$\{ e^*_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e^*_{i_k} \mid 1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n \}$$is a basis for the space of $k$-linear alternating maps on $V$, where $(e_1^*,\ldots, e^*_{n})$ denotes the dual basis for $V^*$. One applies this linear algebra pointwise, for each tangent space of a manifold. So, for example, $dx \wedge dy$ is something that takes two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ and spits $$(dx \wedge dy)(X,Y) = \begin{vmatrix}dx(X) & dx(Y) \\ dy(X) & dy(Y) \end{vmatrix}.$$

Comment: (Caveat: C. Falcon's normalization convention for the alternator is different than mine's. There isn't anything wrong with either one, but you should always pay attention to not mix stuff up)

Comment: In fact, I am used to the same convention, it was a typo on my part while avoiding to define $\operatorname{Alt}$ and $\otimes$. :)

Comment: Well, at least now OP knows that are different conventions out there. Hopefully he can first learn the best one, ours lol

Comment: Lol you guys went a bit too in depth for me. This is a vector calculus course so we tend to stay away from the linear algebra side of things for the most part. I've yet to hear the prof even mention vector spaces or bases in lecture

Comment: @IvoTerek, Instead of f=g=0, wouldn't fdx = -gdy be something else to satisfy  ω∧dz=0?
Because then fdx∧dz+gdy∧dz = -gdy∧dz+gdy∧dz which is also 0, no?

Comment: You **need** the linear algebra to understand stuff right. And $f\,dx=-g\,dy$ implies $f=g=0$ since $dx$ and $dy$ are also linearly independent

Comment: Yes but why are they linearly independent? I understand the concept of linear independence of a set of vectors but how are dx and dy linearly independent in this case?

Comment: They are elements of a certain vector space, so it makes sense to ask if they're linearly independent. Take a look at Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*, for example